# Android error : com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified

Tags: android, admob

My project android have error when i using admob run in android 5.1
application show log error :

```html
11-15 01:16:13.645 1143-1143/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1143: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
11-15 01:16:13.776 2356-21878/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified.
```

This is content my build.gradle file:

```html
compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.exam"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.00"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.5.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.5.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:1.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I tried many solution but it not work
Thank for any can fix it. Please help me!

Comment: I suugest you replace `implemention` with `compile`

Comment: @amir133 i tried as you comment but it not working

Comment: Three question : **1.** can you build and run your project on `android 5.1` **2.** Did you have this problem on every android 5.1 device(maybe your play service is outOfDate). **3.** did android studio offer some warning or error in `build.gradle` if true I suggest you solve them.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
```

If you are using 17+ AdMob sdk you need to specify app id in AndroidManifest.xml file. You can find your app id in Admob App settings

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

after adding above code try uninstalling the app manually and reinstall again without making any changes. Also replace your compile with implementation.

Comment: i tried as you comment above but it not working. i run it on android 5.1 Application not start and show error : "11-16 01:16:28.655 1144-1144/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1144: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
11-16 01:16:28.726 1933-2191/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified."  With device run android 7 Application run ok

Comment: If it's not confidential could you please send complete code to my email address? Here is my email address gutteraj7@gmail.com I will check and find out what is the problem.

Comment: So sorry.This is project of my company. i can't send for you source full but
I will try create small project had this error and send for you after complete.
Thanks you very much