# Api 23: NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified. error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have a error in api 23 when i run my app:

> "NetworkScheduler: Invalid component specified"

I don't have this error api 28-24

whats the problem?

Comment: Same problem here - API 24 - did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306760/android-error-com-google-android-gms-persistent-e-networkscheduler-invalid-co